# Sorting np arrays according to another list

Tags: python, neural-network

I am working on a project with convolutional neural networks. I already trained my model (binary) and got nice results. Then I inserted my data and used the model to predict outcomes. My output is in the form of np array of an image + the value of prediction as shown on the image in the link below. Now, I am trying to sort my np arrays of images (labelled F in the screenshot) according to predictions (ynew in the screenshot) in descending order. I need that in order to get my F with the highest and lowest prediction as I am going to use them for building another dataset.
I've been stuck on that sorting problem for days now and I can't seem to get it right, I tried with zipped lists and some other techniques but can't get what I want.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/giTk6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that all you need, is to sort `ynew`, but more specifically to get the indices of sorted elements using `np.argsort`. E.g. for

```
ynew = np.array([0.6, 0.9, 0.7])
```

The sorted indices you'll get with `np.argsort(ynew)` would be `[0, 2, 1]` (in ascending order). Now you'll only need to use these indices to get images at those specified indices like so:

```
sorted_indices = np.argsort(ynew)
sorted_images = F[sorted_indices]
```

Thus `sorted_images` will be orderered in ascending order of `ynew`, you can reverse the indices preemptively like `sorted_indices = np.argsort(ynew)[::-1]`